# How do you access an array you created as part of a class constructor in your other methods?

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm creating a project to display a Spreadsheet. 
As part of the project, I created a Spreadsheet class that has basic functions such as constructing a Spreadsheet, returning the number of rows in a spread sheet, returning the number of columns in a spread sheet etc.

I started by creating a constructor for Spreadsheet to create a 2D array (20 rows, 12 columns) of empty cell objects.

```
public Spreadsheet() {
  EmptyCell[][] spreadsheet = new EmptyCell[20][12]; 
}
```

I also have two other methods, getRows() and getCols() that returns the number of rows and columns in the spreadsheet (so it should return 20 and 12 respectively).

```
public int getRows() {      
  return spreadsheet.length();
}
```

However, I realized that I cannot access the spreadsheet 2D array I created as part of the Spreadsheet constructor. Is there a way for me to access this in other methods outside of my constructor method?

EDIT: I also cannot just pass the spreadsheet array as a parameter because the getRows() and getCols() methods are implemented from an interface and these methods do not accept a parameter.

Comment: You need to declare `spreadsheet` outside the constructor (in the class body). Whether you create (initialize) it in a constructor or not, it needs to be declared in the class body to be accessible to all methods.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the start of the array just after the main void like,

```
public class your_name{
EmptyCell[][] spreadsheet;
}
```

and in your main constructor or method complete the process

```
public class onCreate (or the constructor name){
spreadsheet = new String [][];
}
```